Prove that the sets $A_0, A_1, ..., A_n$ of length k, where $n > k(k-1)$, all have a common number if every pair of them has exactly 1 common number
Let $n \text{ and } k$ be natural numbers, and $n \gt k^2 - k$. If $A_0, A_1, A_2, \cdots, A_n$ be sets of natural numbers of length $k$, where every pair of $A_i, A_j$ have exactly one common element, meaning $\left| A_i \cap A_j\right| = 1$. Then there exists a number X s.t. $X \in {\bigcap_{i = 0}^n A_i}$.
I was thinking of using the pigeonhole principle. Denoting $x_i$ as $A_0 \cap A_i$ for every $i$ from $1$ to $n$. So now $\{x_1, x_2, \cdots, x_n\} \subset A_0$. and by the pigeonhole principal at least $\lceil{\frac{n}{k}}\rceil$ of them are equal. but couldn't advance it any further.

Is the inequality $n\geq k^2-k$ or $n>k^2-k$?

@MaxChien It's $n \gt k^2 - k$. Note that there are $n + 1$ sets in $A_0, A_1, A_2, \cdots, A_n$.
The statement is not true if you allow equality: For example, when $k=2$ and $n=2$ then we can have $A_0 = {6,7}, A_1 = {6,8}, A_2 = {7,8}$.

@ChristopherWells Thanks, that's what I was thinking. In that case, we can assume that $n=k^2-k+1$ by taking subcollections of that size. If there is some way to appropriately relabel the numbers in the sets such that $i\in A_j\iff j\in A_i$ and $i\notin A_i$, then this would be solved by Erdos's Friendship Theorem

@MaxChien I believe this is solvable without Edro's friendship theorem, but a solution with it would also be appreciated

Lemma: Each $x$ that does not appear in all the $A_i$s appears in at most $k$ of them.
Proof: Let $S$ be the set of $A_i$ which do contain $x$. The elements of $S$ are "distinct except for $x$", meaning they contain no other common elements.
Let $j$ be such that $A_j$ is not in $S$. It has exactly one element in common with each element of $S$. $A_j$ has $k$ elements in all, and each is in common with at most one element of $S$ - since only $x$ is in common with two elements of $S$, and $x$ is not in $A_j$. And since every element of $S$ must have an element in common with $A_j$, $S$ has at most $k$ elements.

Now the main result. $A_0$ contains $k$ elements. Assuming none of them appear in all the $A_i$s, then by the above lemma, each can appear at most $k$ times across all the $A_i$s. One of those appearances, in $A_0$, is already accounted for.
So each element in $A_0$ appears in at most $k-1$ other sets. So there are at most $k(k-1)$ sets that share any common element with $A_0$, so $n$ is at most $k(k-1)$. This is a contradiction, so our assumption that none of them appear across all the $A_i$s is incorrect.
